# ffmpeg issue when converting audio to png to stdout, but is ok to file

Tags: ffmpeg, stdout

when I try to convert an audio to an image (amplitude spectrum) sending its data to stdout (it's embedded in a script so I do not need to write on disk) it fails

```
ffmpeg -y -f alaw -ar 8000 -i 282578800275916.8000-audio-pcma -frames:v 1 -filter_complex aformat=channel_layouts=mono,compand,showwavespic=s=183322x15 -f png -  2>> ffmpegDrawErr.log
```

I got in the log:
*Requested output format 'png' is not a suitable output format*

But if I run it directly to a file

```
ffmpeg -y -f alaw -ar 8000 -i 282578800275916.8000-audio-pcma -frames:v 1 -filter_complex aformat=channel_layouts=mono,compand,showwavespic=s=183322x15 out.png  2>> ffmpegDrawErr.log
```

It works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For image formats, there is a generic set of muxers (image2 and image2pipe). Format is set using the codec option.

`ffmpeg -y -f alaw -ar 8000 -i 282578800275916.8000-audio-pcma -frames:v 1 -filter_complex aformat=channel_layouts=mono,compand,showwavespic=s=183322x15 -c:v png -f image2pipe - 2>> ffmpegDrawErr.log`